# A code that draw image using the C++'s CDC can use as the same in Java?

Tags: java, draw, cdc

I have some codes that draw image using c++'s CDC. Now I am trying to use those codes as it is to draw image in java canvas. Is this really possible or impossible? I will wait your answers.

Comment: Do you want to copy/paste your C++ code into a Java source file, or call your C++ code from Java?

Comment: Yes, I have some source codes to draw images. And now I am trying to use it as it is.

Comment: Are you aware that Java and C++ are not the same language at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you can't use the c++ codes as it is in the android phone.
Because android phone's is based on linux, but c++ is not. so the between the different systems, can't transform.

Comment: This has to be one of the oddest accepted answers I have ever seen.

Comment: @Captain Giraffe not only that...
he's implying that "c++ is not based on linux"...
how can a Programming language be based on an OS Kernel?
also... where in the OP's post did Android get called to this?
and lastly... I'll have whatever he's drinking.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas fulfills the role of java Graphics(2D) or Windows CDC.
Canvas.setBitmap would seem a good guess to output an image.